# sparse file usage in python

Tags: python, macos, file, filesize, sparse-file

I'm creating sparse files in python as follows:

```
>>> f = open('testfile', 'ab')
>>> f.truncate(1024000)
>>> f.close()
```

when the file is done, it takes up 0 disk space, but its inode size is set to my truncated value (1000K):

```
igor47@piglet:~/test$ ls -lh testfile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor47 igor47 1000K 2010-07-09 04:02 testfile
igor47@piglet:~/test$ du -hs testfile 
0   testfile
```

How do I get the file's real space usage (allocated size) inside python? The `stat` call returns the file's apparent size, and I have no idea how else to get the real usage other than to read the entire file (it may become quite large)

```
>>> os.stat('testfile').st_size
1024000
```

Comment: on a side note, if you are copying sparse files using python's shutil module, this will not work, as shutil doesn't support sparse files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> os.stat('testfile').st_blocks*512
0
```

Tadaa :)

`st_blocks` is the number of 512-byte blocks actually allocated to the file. Note that `st_blocks` is not guaranteed to be present in all operating systems, but those that support sparse files generally do.

Comment: `st_blksize` provides actual block size of the filesystem. Generally speaking it doesn't have to be 512 bytes.

Comment: I was confused for a moment, but that's not true. `st_blksize` is the "preferred" file system block size. `st_blocks` is guaranteed to be in blocks of 512 bytes (see the manpage).

Comment: This particular solution was working this morning, but after i've changed the server machine it suddenly stopped working. Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: this return different value than `du -b` So I think this is wrong

Comment: @Wang no: du -b shows the sparse file size, like ls -l do. du -s and ls -ls shows the real allocated space ( ls -ls shows this in the first column)