# actual size of a file

Tags: python, file, metadata

I am trying to get size of a file that is still downloading by another process. I used the code below(which I found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211999/sparse-file-usage-in-python)):

```
os.stat(filepath).st_blocks*512
```

However, it also return the allocated size of the file. Upon recent inspections, I discovered the accuracy of this solution depends on the OS it's working on. Currently, my OS is ubuntu 12.04 server with ext3 filesystem. Is there another way to find real file size in python?

Comment: The reason you're seeing the wrong size, is perhaps that the downloading application allocates space for the whole file at once. Unless you can interface the downloading process, I'm not sure how you'd do it?

Comment: Probably, but the thing is This method was working correctly in another distro.

Comment: With the same downloading application, same versions and all?

Comment: Yes. I just made a backup of my applications and installed a new OS.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation for `stat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat):

> On some Unix systems (such as Linux), the following attributes may also be available:
>
> - **st_blocks** - number of 512-byte blocks allocated for file
> - **st_blksize** - filesystem blocksize
> - **st_rdev** - type of device if an inode device
> - **st_flags** - user defined flags for file

What you seem to want is `st_blocks * st_blksize`. Do note that this is **not** the actual size of the file, which is the `st_size` member. The number of blocks multiplies by the block size will be *larger* than the actual file size.

---

***Note:*** When it says "**st_blocks** - number of 512-byte blocks allocated for file", the number `512` is actually system-dependent. [The POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) says

> The unit for the *st_blocks* member of the **stat** structure is not defined within POSIX.1-2008. In some implementations it is 512 bytes. It may differ on a file system basis.

If the `st_block` attribute is available, then don't be surprised if it's some other value.

Comment: It seems that ``file_stat.st_blocks * 512`` gives the correct result, regardless of ``st_blksize``. The stat man page (https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) also describes ``st_blksize`` simply as '"preferred" blocksize for efficient file system I/O'.

Comment: The edit to the answer is correct but the answer starts with "What you seem to want is `st_blocks * st_blksize`". This is never correct and there's no relation between `st_blocks` and `st_blksize`. If you can assume Linux then you're assured it's in blocks of 512 but the only portable solution I'm aware of is ST_NBLOCKSIZE  from Gnulib's `stat-size.h`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
os.stat(filepath).st_size
```

Seems it returns what you see in "ls -l"

Comment: What I get from ls -l is also not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of your SO, you can access to the metadata of the file:

```
metadata = os.stat(path_to_file)
metadata.st_size
```

Comment: @Hgeg Then is seems like it's not the _actual size of a file_ that you want.

Comment: What I meant was I want to learn how much space it allocates on the hard drive, not the file size stored in inode, which is the value I get currently.